# Why does the console give wrong output?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

You can see from the pic, I've different output for the same variable folderMetadata. 
I'm selecting the method in the functions stack and the pretend the output as always.
What's going on? (I'm in debug mode, just checked).

[image]

Update:
**NSLog output**:

```
folderMetadata {
    AlbumLookup1 = "<e41e5700 f41e5700 e41e5700 c4b25600 e4b05600 e41e5700 241e5700 b4305700 34275700 00000000 00000000 a42c5700 00000000 00000000 00000000>";
    AlbumLookup2 = "<141f5700 f41e5700 141f5700 c4b25600 e4b05600 141f5700 241e5700 c4305700 34275700 00000000 00000000 e42c5700 00000000 00000000 00000000>";
    Artist = "<84235700 b4205700 a4205700 74df5600 e4b05600 84295700 f4325700 04335700 64275700 00000000 00000000 a4295700 00000000 00000000 00000000>";
```

Comment: Dont trust the Debugger Variables view (the one on the left side). I don't know why, but it is sometimes just wrong. - `po` in the debugger console, or `NSLog()` in the code is reliable.

Comment: @MartinR OK, however it turned out that the NSLog output is actually agreeing with the stack variable. The po command seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the sideeffects of the optimization compiler does, hopefully going to be fixed in upcoming Xcode versions